# How to undo/redo a sortable action in jqueryui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, undo-redo

I have a sortable list(jquery ui), could you advise if it is possible to implement 'undo/redo' base on sortable?

Imagine that, a item is dragged to a new placeholder, then I click "undo" button and the item will move to its original position. If I click "redo" button and the item will move to that new placeholder.

Maybe someone knows how to do this or maybe something else. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After each move (on [`update`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-update)), you could store the [serialized](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize) (or use [`toArray`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-toArray)) order in a variable, and then use that to re-order your items in the event of an "undo." In fact, you could push the serialized data onto an array, giving you the ability to "undo" several times.